# I need help adding values in a txt file to a set of tuples

Tags: python, file, floating-point, set, tuples

I'm given a txt file like so:

```
1.0 5.0
2.0 8.0
3.5 12.5
```

I need to take these values and make them tuples within a set
my output  should be:

```
[(1.0, 5.0), (2.0, 8.0), (3.5, 12.5)]
```

Stuck on how to do this, simple python only if possible.

This is my code so far:

```
import sys
def read_points(filename: str) -> Set[Tuple[float, float]]:

    file = open(filename)
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [item.strip("\n") for item in lines]
    newList = set()
    for item in lines:
            item = item.split(" ")
            item = tuple(float(items) for items in item)
            newList.update(item)                
    file.close()
    print (newList)
```

I keep getting a 'NoneType' object is not iterable and I don't know why any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe your problem is that you don't use `return newList` so it automatically return `None` and in other part of code you use this `None` instead of `newList`. Full error message could explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't throw an exception for me, but doesn't work the way you expect it to. When you call `newList.update(item)` method you actually add every element in this tuple to set instead of adding the whole tuple. The correct code here would be

```
newList.add(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace of the error always says which line is the one in which the error occurred, but by your message, this information is required to better understand the problem, but with the information you gave, I can tell that the problem happened when something was trying to iterate over a None, in this case this operation is not valid since NoneType is not iterable.

This situation can happen in the following places in your code:

```
lines = [item.strip("\n") for item in lines]
```

if lines is None

```
for item in lines:
```

if lines is None

```
item = tuple(float(items) for items in item)
```

if item is None.

The first two you need to make sure the filename points to a file that exists, otherwise readlines() will read nothing

Now, for what you're trying to achieve, you're going in the right direction. I have a few questions of my own though. Why is newList a set? I would totally use a list there for simplicity. I will assume you will use a list from now on, the rest of the solution could look something like this:

```
>>> newList = [1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0, 3.5, 12.5]
>>> it = iter(newList)
>>> solution = {(x,y) for x,y in zip(it,it)}
>>> solution
set([(1.0, 5.0), (3.5, 12.5), (2.0, 8.0)])
```

I hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you've used update method instead of add.
From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

> s.update(t) - return set s with elements added from t
>   s.add(x) - add element x to set s

You can easily fix your code like this:

```py
import sys
from typing import Tuple, Set


def read_points(filename: str) -> Set[Tuple[float, float]]:

    file = open(filename)
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [item.strip("\n") for item in lines]
    newList = set()
    for item in lines:
            item = item.split(" ")
            item = tuple(float(items) for items in item)
            newList.add(item)                 
    file.close()
    print (newList)
```